# a quality of being risky and dangerous but highly rewarding

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an adjective to express a quality of being risky and dangerous but highly rewarding?

Answer (score 1):

In the context of finance/investment *High risk, high reward* is often used.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous phrases (not single word adjectives) suggesting these characteristics, mostly deriving from betting or sports idioms, including

> - go for broke
> - shoot the moon
> - shoot the works
> - tempt fortune
> - buck the odds
> - take a flyer
> - hail mary pass

Answer (score -1):

Per M-W Unabridged, something that's *speculative* is anything "involving relatively high risk and usually an unusual potentiality for gain."

Comment: That seems like a bad definition of the word. Speculation in the context of trading means when the trade is based on making profit purely on the changing market value of the asset, rather than the intrinsic value of the asset. (eg a speculator, upon seeing a bubble, might invest knowing that the asset is overvalued, with the hope of selling a the peak of the bubble. A non speculator will not.).

Comment: @user1068446 Where in the OP's question is _trading_ mentioned at all?

Comment: Ok, _trading_ might have been a too specific term to use. But any finance/investment action. Your definition deals with making/losing money, you wouldn't use speculative in the context of walking a tight rope or asking a colleague on a date.

Comment: @user1068446 Read the OP's question again, and answer what's being asked, not what you think is being asked: "an adjective to express a quality of being risky and dangerous but highly rewarding." Do you see anything about finance or investment in there?